# Over 100% gives negative number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I get a final percentage value say for example 96%, I want to give the difference between this and 100%, that is ok but if the percentage value is over 100% it gives me it in a negative number.

`=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18), "", (100% -E18))`

So if 96% is percentage value I get 4% in this cell

If 105% is percentage value I get -5% in this cell.

Any ideas, really easy i am sure but just cant think at the moment.

Comment: For future reference this is better asked on Super User as it is not programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18), "", ABS(100% -E18))
```

Just return the absolute value.

However the difference IS negative, so just be sure that it is in fact the absolute difference that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much Dan, I will accept your answer later on.

Comment: @user445714 why not accept it now? 1 click .....

Comment: @brettdj there is a minimum amount of time before you can accept an answer

Comment: @Dan .....there you go. Didn't realise that given my small amount of questions. thx

Comment: Wow thats a bit much brettdj, not that it was anything to do with you but i sat and hit refresh till the 6 minutes was up to keep you happy.

Comment: @user445714 as my comment to Dan clearly indicated (7 minutes prior to your post) I had no idea there was a time limit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you want to handle the negative outcomes

For example to return 0 if the answer is less than 0 you could use

`=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18), "", MAX(0,100% -E18))`

Or you could

- Provide a warning to the user that the data appears out of bounds `=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18), "",IF(100%-E18<0,"negative",100% -E18))`
- Return nothing `=IF(OR(100%-E18<0,ISERROR(100%-E18)),"",100%-E18)`
- Use `ABS` to return 5% rather then -5% (as Dan did)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ABS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/abs-HP005208978.aspx) function to get the absolute value of your difference.

=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18), "", ABS((100% -E18)))